# jQuery Accordion - Move the selected one up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Guys I'm doing a jQuery accordion kind of a thing using slide function. It works fine but i'm using this for a project which requires me to move the selected one to up or to first one.

Here's my HTML and jQuery

```
<ul class="inneraccordion">
            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-l_offers"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">Offers (3)</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-l_play"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">Set Top Box</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-l_sim"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">Sim Cards</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-l_voucher"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">Vouchers</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-l_pin"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">E-Pins</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

            <li>                    
                <a href="#" class="open">
                    <div class="acc_head row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 icon-divider"><div class="icon-layers"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 acc_head_text">Bundles</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="inneraccordionbox">
                    Content
                </div>                       
            </li>

        </ul>
```

jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var open = $('.open'),
        a = $('ul').find('a');

    console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

    open.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            speed = 500;
        if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
            $this.removeClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideUp(speed);
        } else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
            $this.addClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideDown(speed);
        } else {
            a.removeClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').slideUp(speed);
            $this.addClass('active').next('.inneraccordionbox').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS incase if you need -

```
/* inner accordion */
.acc_head {
height: 90px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e9ec;
}
.icon-divider, .acc_head_text {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 90px;
padding:0 20px;
}
.icon-divider {
border-right: 1px solid #ececec;       
}
.icon-divider div {
margin: 0 auto;    
}
.icon-divider div::before {
font-size: 44px;
color:#3fb3ec;
}
.acc_head_text {
background: url('../images/plus.png') no-repeat 97% 35px !important;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
color:#444444;
font-family: "Gotham Medium", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
font-size: 20px;
}
a.active .acc_head_text {
background: url('../images/cross.png') no-repeat 97% 35px !important;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.inneraccordionbox {    
height:300px;
position:relative;
display:none;
padding: 0px;

}
.inneraccordion li {
background: #fff;
display:block;
padding-right:10px;
list-style:none;
border: 1px solid #e1e9ec;
border-bottom: none;
border-radius:3px; 
-moz-border-radius:3px; 
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px rgba(221,222,224,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px rgba(221,222,224,1);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px rgba(221,222,224,1);
margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
.inneraccordion li:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You can use .get() to get active element and then .remove() and then .prepend() to add on top of accordion elements

Answer (score 0):

I've added following code inside this - `else if(a.hasClass('active') === false)` condition. It moves the selected element 1 position upwards.

```
li = $(this).parent();
li.insertBefore(li.prev(li));
li.slideUp(500, function(){
      //callback
}).slideDown(500);
```

To move the selected element to the top of your list, change `li.insertBefore(li.prev(li));` to `li.insertBefore(li.siblings(":eq(0)"));`

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aza08uwk/1/)

Comment: Only the second list moves to 1st position.

Comment: Uncomment following code in my fiddle and every element will move to 1st position.. `//li.insertBefore(li.siblings(":eq(0)"));` . You've not specified which case is necessary to move the selected element up once or to the top of your list. ("...which requires me to move the selected one to up or to first one...."), so there are 2 lines of code, one to move it 1 position upwards and one to move your element to the top of your list. Comment one out and set the unused under comment tag and you'll get your solution possibilities.